# Do regular mummies reform when destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

When [reading the lore on Mummies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-m#Mummies) (MM, p. 227), it says:

> **Ending a Mummy's Curse.** Rare magic can undo or dispel the ritual that gave rise to a mummy, allowing it to truly die.

Now clearly the Mummy Lord doesn't die permanently when destroyed (it says so right in the stat-block), but does a normal Mummy stay destroyed if you defeat it?  Or will it eventually reform and continue to move around?

Is there any additional lore information (from older editions, perhaps?) about what happens to a regular Mummy that gets defeated in combat? Or should I just assume that this part specifically refers to Mummy Lords only, and ordinary mummies just stay down?

Answer (score 9):

## No they do not reform

The reason why the Mummy Lord reforms is in the Mummy Lord lore section.

> **Heart of the Mummy Lord.** As part of the ritual that creates a mummy lord, the creature's heart and viscera are removed from the
> corpse and placed in canopic jars... As long as its shriveled heart
> remains intact, a mummy lord can't be permanently destroyed.

This part of the ritual is not done for a normal mummy.

Furthermore, the part about ending a mummy's curse is not referring to the ability for a mummy to come back to life, but to exist in the first place. The ritual of creating a mummy sets a trigger that causes the mummy to rise from its eternal slumber and attack whoever disturbed it. Dispelling this curse through rare magic, makes it so they are no longer a mummy and won't rise to this trigger.

You can also lull the mummy back to it's eternal slumber by undoing whatever was done that caused the trigger. However, if you lull the mummy back to it's slumber by these means, the mummy can then rise again if the trigger is activated once more. More offensive or unrecoverable actions can only be remedied by defeating the mummy in combat or through "rare magic" to remove the curse entirely.

Comment: "This part of the ritual is not done for a normal mummy" - actually, it is. Check out the first headlined paragraph of the mummies lore text: "Preserved Wrath. The long burial rituals that accompany a mummy's entombment help protect its body from rot. In the embalming process, the newly dead creature's organs are removed and placed in special jars, and its corpse is treated with preserving oils, herbs, and wrappings". That *does* sound like the same thing is done to regular mummies. Nonetheless, I don't think regular mummies rejuvenate, otherwise it would be in their stat block.

Comment: @PixelMaster Yes, I must have missed that part. Irregardless, the Mummy Lord has a specific section implying that the ritual is slightly different for them, which gives them the ability to return from dust. And like you said, it would be in their stat block or even an errata by now if all of them were meant to reform.